# How can I create a new object based on the current?

Tags: php, html, class, methods, abstract-class

I have a base class and multiple classes that extends from the base class.

```
class B {}
class C extends B {}
class D extends B {}
```

How can I create a C or D inside the method dynamically from B? what's the best way?

For example I tried:

```
class B {

    function hello() { echo "hello"; }

    function createObject()
    {
        $temp = new self();
        $temp->hello();
    }
}

$t = new C();
$t->createObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right! But you must return your new object like:

```
class B {

    function hello() { echo "hello"; }

    function createObject()
    {
        $temp = new self();
        $temp->hello();
        return $temp; // <--- here
    }
}

$t = new C();
$tNew = $t->createObject();
```

Comment: new self() is creating a new object B not C